# Can someone swear off something that is already prohibited to them by halacha?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, nedarim-shevuot

Can someone swear off something that is already prohibited to them?

For instance: "I swear I won't eat non-kosher."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *sh'vu'as shav* (useless oath). The utterance has no effect because it is not stating or changing anything that was not already binding and true. The opening paragraph [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90_%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%A8) has a couple other examples.

Comment: -1, *mushba veomed mehar sinai* (מושבע ועומד מהר סיני). That means he already swared about it on Sinai, hence swearing again has no effect. [Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=815) is an article for example about that. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9227/1059

Answer (score 1):

I think it is rather called  *mushba veomed mehar sinai* (מושבע ועומד מהר סיני). That means he already swared about it on Sinai, hence swearing again has no effect.

[Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=815) is an article for example about that.

Comment: I believe mushba v'omed says that a shevua to eat non-kosher doesn't begin since you already made a shavua to not eat non-kosher.  zaq is referring to making a shevua that complies with har sinai.  In that case, @WAF's rule comes in.

Comment: @YDK, look here: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97_%D7%90 . Especially this line "והלא מושבע ועומד הוא, ואין שבועה חלה על שבועה"

Comment: You are correct.  I haven't looked at how others learn that piece.  Are you saying that the shevua has no effect in the shevua world, but it's not a shevuas shav because it helps to motivate?